# How to set the path to shapely?

Tags: qgis, mac, osx, shapely

I am using QGIS 1.8.0 on Mac OS 10.8.3 with python 2.7. Thanks to other threads in the forum, I have successfully installed shapely here:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Shapely-1.2.16-py2.7.egg

However, when I try to use the polygonizer-Plugin in QGIS it tells me that it cannot find shapely.ops. This clearly seems to be a path-problem, but I have no other versions of python installed. I have tried to append the above path to .bash-profile, but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

Nils

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: Because my local system is German I thought this would not be very helpful. I solved the issue anyway (see below), but many thanks for caring!

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry but you do not use the legacy version of Python installed by default and QGIS use exclusively this Apple Python, not another version of Python.

The site-packages of the Apple Python is /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages and not /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/. It is another version of Python (from Python.org or Enthought for example) and you must install Shapely in the Apple Python.

To verify, open the terminal (Terminal.app) and type:

For the Apple Python:

```
python
.......
```

```py
>>> import shapely
>>> print shapely.__file__
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Shapely-1.2.17-py2.7.egg/shapely/__init__.pyc'
```

Comment: Stupid me! You are right, during the many installations last night I must have also installed python from Python.org. After removing the files under /Library/Frameworks/... and reinstalling shapely, the Polygonizer works! Many thanks!